# Object as Constructor Parameter to DataContext in XAML

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, objectdataprovider

I have a XAML Windows class

```
<Window 
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:src="clr-namespace:ObjectReferenceSample" 
    Title="ObjectReference Sample" Height="300" Width="300">
    <Window.DataContext>
    <ObjectDataProvider ObjectType="viewModel:MyViewModel">
      <ObjectDataProvider.ConstructorParameters>
        **<!-- MyModel class instance defined in codebehind-->****
      </ObjectDataProvider.ConstructorParameters>
    </ObjectDataProvider>
    </Window.DataContext>
</Window>
```

Also in my code behind I have an instance of MyModel class that needs to be passed as constructor parameter to my ViewModel through ObjectDataProvider.

```
public partial class MyWindow: Window
{
    public MyModel model;
    public MyWindow()
    {
          model = new MyModel();  
    }
}
```

MyViewModel would like:

```
public partial class MyViewModel
{
    public MyViewModel(MyModel modelInstance)
    {

    }
}
```

I have some limitation of not being able to use DI like Unity.  Please suggest me solution of above problem without DI concept only.

Comment: Why not set this DataContext in code behind also? You have your model there already anyway.

Comment: This is an example code i shared. In my actual code i have few more constraints so i am bound to achieve above flow only

Comment: @ABCDEF What constraints? Anyhow, you can initialize properties when you create the instance in XAML, but the constructor must be parameterless.

Comment: I don't understand what you're asking. Does the code you posted work? It seems to me it should, depending on what's actually in the part **you didn't bother to show**. What does the code do? What did you want instead? What _specifically_ do you need help with?